# Socket locks up when killing a process ran with elevated permissions on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, ipc, zeromq

I've run into an issue I'd like to understand more.

I have a C++ application on a Linux machine. Let's call this `program1`. `program1` uses ZeroMQ for IPC communications. I imagine that the ZeroMQ layer has a little to do with the behavior but want to introduce all the facts. If I run `program1` via terminal with no elevated permissions, I can kill it any number of times. I can also run `program1` with Eclipse with no issues.

However, if I run `program1` with elevated permissions:

`$ sudo ./program1`

and kill it (Ctrl+C), the IPC socket locks up and is unavailable for use when trying to run the application without elevated privileges. However, if I rerun the program with elevated permissions, it works just fine.

My theory is that once you run the application with elevated permissions that the file descriptors change ownership to the parent process (with elevated permissions). Then, when you kill the process the file descriptors are never properly cleaned so their permissions are left elevated, unable to be used without the elevated permissions.

Is that on the mark? If so, is there a way to prevent this type of issue in code, or to fix the issue after it occurs without restarting the entire computer?

Updated ******

Updating to add more information:

1) The software does really exit when I hit Ctr+C. It can't be found in the system monitor, even when ran as sudo. (sudo gnome-system-monitor)

2) The socket returns "address already in use" on creation.

3) Ideally, I'd want them to be able to connect to each other no matter how they are ran. This isn't an issue I considered during development and will admit I'm new to Linux and IPC communication.

Comment: The zombie file descriptor theory doesn't sound right to me. What ZeroMQ transport are you using? When you Ctrl+C the program, does it really exit (check that the process really is gone)? Does the program `fork()` off any children? And... are you able to create a [mcve]?

Comment: And what is the _exact_ behavior you described as _"... lock[ed] up and unavailable for use"_?

Comment: We need to see how you're using ZeroMQ. You also have to think through carefully what you want to happen. Do you want all your programs to connect to each other even if they in completely different user/security contexts? Or do you want separate "zones" for different contexts?

Comment: This sounds like something to do with `SO_LINGER`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html  See also `ZMQ_LINGER`: http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-setsockopt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said it: "the IPC socket".

I guess that's not a TCP socket. If zeromq is creating a System V IPC object as root, the user cannot reuse it and that's why the permission error: IPC objects don't get destroyed by the process death and have user ownership and permissions.

You can list the existing IPC objects with the command `ipcs`, remove them with `ipcrm`.

Oh yes - take care not to delete IPC objects not related to your work...

If I failed my guess, you can use the command `strace` to inspect which system call is actually failing to find the real culprit.

Comment: Hey man that seems to be the jist of it. Great answer. I also realized that if one software is ran as sudo and the other isn't, they can't communicate via IPC because of different elevated levels. Great stuff.